# Font Smoothing Chrome Webstore

Tags: google-chrome, typography, google-webfonts

Curious how Google get the headers so smooth in Chrome Webstore (Chrome 33, Windows 7 64bit). They're not using any classic tricks, like `text-shadow`.

[image]